# SVM performance drops in validation

Tags: classification, svm, resampling

I'm checking my ability to predict a binary outcome using SVM. While the model fits very well, when resampling the model performance drops (but not so much when using logistic regression) which makes me think that SVM overfits this model, but as I understand this should not happen unless cost is set to very low. I'm using bootstrap for validation due to the size of my sample size (and not split sample)

In my specific problem I'm using R and caret, I hope this is informative without data.

```
library(caret)
bootControl <- trainControl(method = "boot",number = 50, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
svmFit <- train(y~x1+x2+x3, data = mydata, method = "svmRadial", preProc = c("center", "scale"), trControl = bootControl, tuneLength = 10, metric = "ROC")

print(svmFit)
Support Vector Machines with Radial Basis Function Kernel

435 samples
11 predictors
2 classes: 'Yes', 'No'

Pre-processing: centered (11), scaled (11)
Resampling: Bootstrapped (50 reps)
Summary of sample sizes: 435, 435, 435, 435, 435, 435, ...
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  sigma   C    ROC        Sens       Spec
  0.0500  0.4  0.6304266  0.1251318  0.9657021
  0.0500  0.5  0.6304765  0.1148548  0.9693974
  0.0500  0.6  0.6304535  0.1154509  0.9679899
  0.0736  0.4  0.6204297  0.1174435  0.9585102
  0.0736  0.5  0.6203528  0.1170825  0.9588165
  0.0736  0.6  0.6202821  0.1147403  0.9588918

  ROC was used to select the optimal model using  the largest value.
  The final values used for the model were sigma = 0.05 and C = 0.5.


###############
predict(svmFit, mydata$y) # 100% PPV, 86% NPV, 15% Sens 98% Spec, 70% ROC
confusionMatrix(svmFit) # 41% PPV 86% NPV,2% Sens, 98% Spec, 62% ROC
```

Comment: Have you tried tuning the regularization parameters? This should significantly impact whether you'll over-fit or not.

Comment: The train function does just that through cross validation

Comment: Addition: from additional reading, I see that the low sigma probably is a cause for some overfitting, however it was the best choice based on CV runs (i.e - higher sigma results in very poor model performance.